# hours minutes seconds in each line in a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and looking for a way to read and identify hours minutes seconds in each line in a text file and based that do some computations 
I want to print the sum of salaries= based on hours, so once the hour changes 18 it re-sums the values again

Data from the test file:

```
18:26:18 salaries=300 age=20
18:26:19 salaries=600 age=20
18:26:20 salaries=500 age=20
18:26:21 salaries=230 age=20
18:26:22 salaries=550 age=20

lines = open('C:/path/file.txt').read().splitlines()
```

I tries using `lines[0:1]` but i think it is inefficient way

Comment: Isn't using `csv` file would be more convenient for this task?

Comment: Whats the question here?

Comment: maybe you are right Sherzod and  Chris Doyle i want to automatically identify the date 18:26:18 in each line and based on do computation by avoiding using the index like this lines[0:1]

Comment: Something that involves using to automatically identify %H:%M:%S and sum the values for that hour and then sum the values of next hour and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
lines = [line.split(" ")[0] for line in open('C:/path/file.txt').read().splitlines()]

print(lines)
```

Output:

```
['18:26:18', '18:26:19', '18:26:20', '18:26:21', '18:26:22']
```

or:

```
lines = [line.split(" ")[0].split(":") for line in open('test').read().splitlines()]
```

output:

```
[['18', '26', '18'], ['18', '26', '19'], ['18', '26', '20'], ['18', '26', '21'], ['18', '26', '22']]
```

or:

```
import re

test = re.findall(r'(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)', open('C:/path/file.txt').read())

print(test)
```

output:

```
['18:26:18', '18:26:19', '18:26:20', '18:26:21', '18:26:22']
```

Comment: It is a good solution but i just prefer not to use the index. Something that involves %H:%M:%S

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your file it might be better to stream the file.

```
with open('C:/path/file.txt', 'r') as file: # The 'r' is for read-only access to the file
    while True:
        line = file.readline()
        if not line: # end of file
            break
        time = line[:8].split(':') # Results in a list (hour, minute, second)
        # Do your processing using the time information
```

*Added example for calculation*
If the file only contains values for a single day, you could simply define a dictionary outside of the loop and like so:

```
salaries = {}
with ...
    time = ...
    salary = int(line.split(" ")[1][9:])
    salaries.setdefault(time[0], 0)
    salaries[time[0]] += salary
```

This would result in a dictionary which summed up all the salaries for a single hour and day.

Comment: It is a good solution but i am looking for Something that automatically identifies %H:%M:%S and sum the values for that hour and then sum the values of next hour and so on

Comment: That would require more information about the input. Is is ordered? Is it on a per-day basis?
See my edits in original answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the given test file

Following is the most efficient way available

```
file = open(filename_with_completepath_if_not_in_sameplace_as _the_code, 'r')`
for line in file:
    # the line below splits based on tab, then takes the 1st(0th value) 
    # then splits the 0th value by ':' into a list of three values hr, min, sec
    splited_line = line.split('\t')[0].split[':']
    hr = splited_line[0]
    min = splited_line[1]
    sec = splited_line[2]
    #<*do operations for the given person in the current line of the loop*>
```

Instead of \t for tab you can use just (" ") for spaces and so on...
This way you can extract hr, mins and sec and perform operations line by line for the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from datetime import datetime

with open("data.txt","r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        date_str = datetime.strptime(line.split()[0], "%H:%M:%S")
        print(date_str.hour, date_str.minute)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

**text.txt:**

```
18:26:18 salaries=300 age=20
18:26:19 salaries=600 age=20
18:26:20 salaries=500 age=20
18:26:21 salaries=230 age=20
18:26:22 salaries=550 age=20
```

**The code is:**

```
import re
lines = open('text.txt').read().splitlines()
times = []
for line in lines:
    tmp_str = [s for s in re.findall("^\d{2}[':']\d{2}[':']\d{2}", line)]
    times.append([int(x) for x in tmp_str[0].split(':') if x.isdigit()])

print(times)
```

**The output of this program is:**

```
[[18, 26, 18], [18, 26, 19], [18, 26, 20], [18, 26, 21], [18, 26, 22]]
```

Where each element is the times from the text file in the format *["H","M","S"]*